# How to find element by the short word tag at the end of 'a' tag in HTML?

Tags: python, html, selenium

This is the part of html source I've got.

```
<a class="q qs" href="/search?q=bicycle&amp;source=lnms&amp;tbm=isch&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjLqMK28PPdAhUDdXAKHS_-CrQQ_AUIDygC">Image</a>
```

What I'm trying to do is, to type a keyword in Google default page, and move to image search section. I used `find_element_by_xpath().click()` to go to image search. The problem is, this xpath is not unique for the name of the button, but rather the location of the buttons.

This configuration of buttons differ by the keyword. For example, in case of bicycle, it's like **{'All', 'Image', 'Map'}**, whereas for a computer, it's presented as **{'All', 'Map', 'Image'}**, occurring in wrong search in 'Map' section.

When I looked at the html codes for these buttons, the only difference was the short word tag(I'm not sure what it is called). '**Image**' for my sample code above.

**Question** : How do I specify the button I want? Can I find element with the 'short word tag' at the end of 'a' tag?

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is `short word tag`? Which `Tab` do you want to click? Your code trials?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I don't know the exact name of it. What I am trying to cover is something like ‘Image’ in the code snippet I attached.